# Checking for identical values returned from a mongoDB aggregation pipeline even if the record keys/IDs are different

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a aggregation pipeline in mongoDB that returns three random records but I don't want any of the values for these records to be the same. For example I don't want two instances of transactionDetail saying "foo" even though they are from different records. how can I achieve this?

mongoDB query used

```js
db.TABLE.aggregate([{$match: {   pid:{$ne:00000021},   transactionDetail:{$ne:null} }}, {$limit: 100}, {$sample: {   size: 3 }}, {$project: {   transactionDetail:1,   _id: 0 }}])
```

A sample of the data looks like this

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5da92bb0b3507b13a8d63556"), "pid" : 00000001, "transactionDate" : "2019-10-10 13:05:00", "transactionValue" : 0.00, "transactionDetail" : "HOME & THINGS-C/SPRING RO", "system" : "REDACTED" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5da92bb0b3507b13a8d63557"), "pid" : 00000002, "transactionDate" : "2019-10-10 06:15:29", "transactionValue" : 0.00, "transactionDetail" : "JUICI PATTIES - LIGUANEA ", "system" : "REDACTED" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5da92bb0b3507b13a8d63558"), "pid" : 00000003, "transactionDate" : "2019-10-10 10:52:32", "transactionValue" : 0.00, "transactionDetail" : "MATILDA'S CORNER PHARMACY", "system" : "REDACTED" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5da92bb0b3507b13a8d63559"), "pid" : 00000004, "transactionDate" : "2019-10-10 00:00:00", "transactionValue" : 0.00, "transactionDetail" : null, "system" : "REDACTED" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5da92bb2b3507b13a8d6355a"), "pid" : 00000005, "transactionDate" : "2019-10-11 00:00:00", "transactionValue" : 0.00, "transactionDetail" : null, "system" : "REDACTED" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5da92bb2b3507b13a8d6355b"), "pid" : 00000006, "transactionDate" : "2019-10-10 00:00:00", "transactionValue" : 0.00, "transactionDetail" : null, "system" : "REDACTED" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5da92bb2b3507b13a8d6355c"), "pid" : 00000007, "transactionDate" : "2019-10-10 00:00:00", "transactionValue" : 0.00, "transactionDetail" : null, "system" : "REDACTED" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5da92bb2b3507b13a8d6355d"), "pid" : 00000008, "transactionDate" : "2019-10-10 00:00:00", "transactionValue" : 0.00, "transactionDetail" : "COURTS - CONSTANT SP RD  ", "system" : "REDACTED" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5da92bb2b3507b13a8d6355e"), "pid" : 00000009, "transactionDate" : "2019-10-10 00:00:00", "transactionValue" : 0.00, "transactionDetail" : "COURTS - CONSTANT SP RD  ", "system" : "REDACTED" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5da92bb2b3507b13a8d6355f"), "pid" : 00000010, "transactionDate" : "2019-10-10 13:14:44", "transactionValue" : 0.00, "transactionDetail" : "CARIBBEAN FLAVORS AND FRA", "system" : "REDACTED" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5da92bb2b3507b13a8d63560"), "pid" : 00000011, "transactionDate" : "2019-10-10 17:47:40", "transactionValue" : 0.00, "transactionDetail" : "HUA SQUARE LIMITED       ", "system" : "REDACTED" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5da92bb2b3507b13a8d63561"), "pid" : 00000012, "transactionDate" : "2019-10-10 16:28:02", "transactionValue" : 0.00, "transactionDetail" : "UNIPET - GREGORY PARK    ", "system" : "REDACTED" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5da92bb2b3507b13a8d63562"), "pid" : 00000013, "transactionDate" : "2019-10-10 00:00:00", "transactionValue" : 0.00, "transactionDetail" : "DIGICEL DING*    ", "system" : "REDACTED" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5da92bb2b3507b13a8d63563"), "pid" : 00000014, "transactionDate" : "2019-10-10 12:34:55", "transactionValue" : 0.00, "transactionDetail" : "HI-LO - CROSS ROADS      ", "system" : "REDACTED" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5da92bb2b3507b13a8d63564"), "pid" : 00000015, "transactionDate" : "2019-10-11 00:00:00", "transactionValue" : 0.00, "transactionDetail" : "FIRE MOUNTAIN GEMS & BEAD", "system" : "REDACTED" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5da92bb2b3507b13a8d63565"), "pid" : 00000016, "transactionDate" : "2019-10-10 00:00:00", "transactionValue" : 0.00, "transactionDetail" : "AMZN Mktp US*   ", "system" : "REDACTED" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5da92bb2b3507b13a8d63566"), "pid" : 00000017, "transactionDate" : "2019-10-11 04:23:08", "transactionValue" : 0.00, "transactionDetail" : "UBER   TRIP              ", "system" : "REDACTED" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5da92bb2b3507b13a8d63567"), "pid" : 00000018, "transactionDate" : "2019-10-10 18:48:37", "transactionValue" : 0.00, "transactionDetail" : "SHOPPERS FAIR - MANDEVILL", "system" : "REDACTED" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5da92bb2b3507b13a8d63568"), "pid" : 00000019, "transactionDate" : "2019-10-10 06:33:29", "transactionValue" : 0.00, "transactionDetail" : "RUBIS WATERLOO - MLT G A ", "system" : "REDACTED" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5da92bb2b3507b13a8d63569"), "pid" : 00000020, "transactionDate" : "2019-10-10 21:31:23", "transactionValue" : 0.00, "transactionDetail" : "EASYWORSHIP              ", "system" : "REDACTED" }
```

As you can see records 00000008 and 00000009 contains the same transactionDetail Value but I don't want the pipeline to return that.

Here is my pipeline so far.

```py
[
    {
        '$match': {
            'pid': {
                '$ne': idnum
            }, 
            'transactionDetail': {
                '$ne': None
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$limit': 1000
    }, {
        '$sample': {
            'size': 3
        }
    }, {
        '$project': {
            'transactionDetail': 1, 
            '_id': 0
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Please provide sample documents for your collection...

Comment: Please provide the entire query, not just the predicates

Comment: I've updated the question as requested. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried to run the aggregation but get an error - idnum is not defined.  What is idnum supposed to be?

Comment: idnum would be a variable that holds a given 'pid'. Sorry I had taken it straight out of some python code I was using.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan.  I realize this is sample data, but just so I am clear, when looking at your sample data the only one item that *could* be duplicate is "COURTS - CONSTANT SP RD  " - correct?

Comment: There could be more, I'm not fully versed with the dataset but I suspect that multiple persons would go to the same location to make a transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So looking at the sample data set, and looking at the query presented, the only field desired for output is 'transactionDetail'.  I believe you want 3 random unique/distinct/mutually exclusive values.  I think this query does that...

```
db.TABLE.aggregate(
[
    { '$match': {
            'pid': { '$ne': "00000021" }, 
            'transactionDetail': { '$ne': null }
    }},
    { $group: {
        _id: '$transactionDetail',
        count: { $sum: 1}
    }},
    { '$limit': 1000 }, 
    { '$sample': { 'size': 3 } },
    { '$project': {
            '_id': 1
        }
    }
]
)
```

The strategy is to use the $group to map-reduce the duplicates into unique values before performing $sample.

Does this achieve what you are seeking?